# How to copy MS office dll to local folder

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-office

I need to copy MS office dll from following references paths and this is my client asked. Can I do this? If yes, How??

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Office\12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

Comment: I think the path would be C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\GAC.... and so on.
and yes you can copy it. But I would recommend googling it before asking the question.

Comment: Just set the Copy Local property to true.  You really should use the Embed Interop Types feature in VS2010 so you don't have dependency on these PIAs anymore.